# CSS Grid container not taking the width of its children

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Using CSS grid, I expected the grid container (parent) to take it's width from the maximum of its children widths - the way a  gets it's width from the content inside it.

```css
body {
  min-width: 360px;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}

.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "content" "footer";
  grid-template-columns: minmax(1200px, 100%);
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  background: green;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
}

main {
  grid-area: content;
  background: orange;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <header>head</header>
  <main>content</main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

But it looks like I might be out of date on this. I expected the `div.wrap` to be 1200px, like all the children, but instead it's... ? ~500px wide? Is this just how Grid works?

How can I get `div.wrap` to match the width of the children in this instance? Here is codepen link for above:
https://codesandbox.io/s/3ox029p2p - all relevant markup/style in index.html.

Comment: Switch to `inline-grid` (note that *block-level elements* take the width of the viewport) and add `min-width: 100vw` to the `wrap` element. see https://jsfiddle.net/L1vd8afh/ will convert this to answer if that is the requirement... also create a snippet in the answer in addition to the stackblitz...

Comment: @kukkuz you are awesome.  `inline-grid` wins!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comments to this question, you can switch to *inline-grid* (note that *block-level elements* take the width of the viewport by default and if the inner elements exceed this value it just *overflows*) and use `min-width: 100vw` to the `wrap` element - see demo below:

```css
body {
  min-width: 360px;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}

.wrap {
  display: inline-grid; /* changed */
  min-width: 100vw; /* added */
  grid-template-areas: "header" "content" "footer";
  grid-template-columns: minmax(1200px, 100%);
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  background: green;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
}

main {
  grid-area: content;
  background: orange;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <header>head</header>
  <main>content</main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```